# Set timeout on URL.openStream() Android

Tags: android, xml, url

I am using the following in my app to connect to a URL and parse the resulting XML response.  My trouble is I can not figure out a way to set a timeout on the openStream() method so that it only waits about 5 seconds and if no response is received, fails.  It just keeps waiting and waiting.  Any thoughts?

```
URL website = new URL(sb.toString());                         
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
DataHandler h = new DataHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(h);              
xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.  By using URLConnection and calling the setConnectionTimeout and setReadTimeout methods I am able to achieve what I want.  Updated code below....

```
URLConnection conn = new URL(sb.toString()).openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
DataHandler h = new DataHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(h);              
xr.parse(new InputSource(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change it on the URL:

```
website.openConnection().setReadTimeout(5000);
website.openConnection().setConnectTimeout(5000);
```